# Magento Custom Dropdown Column in Manage Product Grid Disappears the Colums when i apply filter

Tags: product, grid, grid-serlization

I wanted to add custom column called brands(dropdown) in magento product grid in backend.I achieved this task but the issue is when i start filter the brands the column brands disappers and when i refresh the page then comes back.can any one please help me.
Here is my code.

in _prepareCollection() function i added

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('brands'); // added by me
```

in _prepareColumns()

```
$brands = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_option')->getCollection()->setStoreFilter()->join('attribute','attribute.attribute_id=main_table.attribute_id','attribute_code');
        foreach($brands as $brand):
            if($brand->getAttributeCode() == 'brands')
                $brand_options[$brand->getOptionId()] = $brand->getValue();
            endforeach;

        $this->addColumn('brands',
            array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Brands'),
            'width' => '10px',
            'index' => 'brands',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'sortable' => false,
            'options' => $brand_options,
        ));
```

Answer (score 10):

First add the add new function on grid.php getAttributeOptions

```
  protected function _getAttributeOptions($attribute_code)
        {
            $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code);
            $options = array();
            foreach( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false, true) as $option ) {
                $options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
            }
            return $options;
        }
```

then 
add modify

```
$this->addColumn('brands', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Brand'),
            'align' => 'left',
            'width' => '80px',
            'index' => 'brands',
```

'final_index' =>'brands',

```
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => $this->_getAttributeOptions('brands'),
        ));
```

Comment: i had used your code and still the same issue.when i filter brands by any brand name the the column brands dissapers and it will come back when i refresh the page.

Comment: please check... final add 'final_index' =>'brands'>also enable brands attribute  in product listing from Manage Attribute>USed in Product listing

Comment: still the same issue.i had checked the product listing is selected to Yes in product listing page.and after adding final_index also not working.

Comment: Pradeep ,this code is working on my system...

Comment: oh.may be it will some other issue on my system.need to debug.thanks a lot.